# jqGrid Add Row is not working

Tags: jqgrid

The Get, Edit and Delete all work fine.  But add will not call into my ActionResult method.  I am using the inline add that displays a modal form for new record values.  There seem to be very few examples of how this works with the pager/form method that is provided in the latest jqGrid release.  What am I missing for add/insert here?

html:

```
            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                url: 'ABC.Admin/CourseAdmin/GetLocationData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['Location Id', 'Name', 'Address Line 1'],
                colModel: [
              { name: 'LocationId', index: 'LocationId', width: 40, key: true },
              { name: 'LocationName', index: 'LocationName', width: 150, editable: true },
              { name: 'AddressLine1', index: 'AddressLine1', width: 150, editable: true },
              ],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 20,
                sortname: 'Name',
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: '***Testing***',
                height: 200,
                loadonce: true, // needs to be true for client side paging to work
                autowidth: true,
                loadtext: 'Loading...'
            })
            $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true },
            { // edit options 
                url: 'ABC.Admin/CourseAdmin/SaveLocation/',
                closeAfterEdit: true
            },
            { // add
                url: 'ABC.Admin/CourseAdmin/Create/'
            },
            { //delete
                url: 'ABC.Admin/CourseAdmin/DeleteLocation/',
                closeOnEscape: true
            }
        );
```

controller:

<strike>public ActionResult Create(int id, string locationName, string addressLine1)</strike>

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateLocation(string oper, string id, string locationName, string addressLine1)        {
            //Models.LocationProvider lp = new Models.LocationProvider();
            //bool saved = lp.InsertLocation(location);
            bool saved = false;
            if (!saved)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                return Content("Record not saved!");
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked out. The types on the parameters in the Create method sig were mismatched.  They need to be all strings.  Changing my controller to the following works.  I also noticed that the *id* and *oper* params are picked up by name, not order - so I can put them either first or last (or wherever) in the signature and they get the correct values - cool!. I will edit my original post with this correction.

```
        public ActionResult Create(string oper, string id, string locationName, string addressLine1)
```

For anyone else looking for jqGrid add/insert examples I hope this one helps out.